# Match string with dot and without

Tags: php, regex

Right now I have regex like:

`([1-9]{0,9}m - [0-9]{0,9}m)`

Which matches phrases like `1m - 5m`, `7m - 17m` etc.

Sometimes string could be`1.5m - 5m`.

How can i match such strings too ?

Comment: To match a float number use `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?`

Comment: @Jonuux Did you really mean to use `[1-9]{0,9}m`? Do you want it to match `m` (no number) but not `10m`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add optional decimal part with `(?:\.\d+)?`:

```
([1-9]{0,9}(?:\.\d+)?m\h*-\h*\d{0,9}(?:\.\d+)?m)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jO6iA1/2)

If the first number can be any, replace `[1-9]` with `\d`.

The `(?:\.\d+)?` means *match a literal dot followed by one or more digits one or zero (`?`) times*.

The `\h*` matches zero or more horizontal whitespaces.

Details:

- `[1-9]{0,9}` - 0 to 9 digits from the `1` to `9` range (**replace with `\d` to match any digits**)
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - optional decimal part
- `m` - literal `m`
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace
- `-` - literal hyphen
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace
- `\d{0,9}` - any digit, 0 to 9 occurrences
- `(?:\.\d+)?m` - see above.

If you plan to prevent matching leading zeros in numbers, but accept strings like `101m - 5m`, you might want to use

```
((?!0)\d{0,9}(?:\.\d+)?m\h*-\h*\d{0,9}(?:\.\d+)?m)
 ^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jO6iA1/4). The lookahead will just restrict the generic `\d` to not start with a `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

`\d+(\.\d+){0,1}m\s-\s\d+(\.\d+){0,1}m`

- number with `.` after it must have digits.so thought it together.But it must be once or ZERO.so...